# How to "find -exec" inside a custom bash function?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create a function that archives all files older than some pre-specified file. I have this so far:

`archive_gs() { find "$GS" -maxdepth 1 -not -newer "$1" -exec mv -t "$GS/../old/" {} \; }`

however this returns an `syntax error: unexpected end of file` error. I'm assuming this is something to do with unescaped curly braces? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, `{` and `}` work like keywords, not punctuation – if the closing `}` is on the same line as a command, then the command must end with `;` or some other separator. (In other words, `{ x; }` works exactly like `do x; done` or `if x; then x; fi`.)

The existing `\;` does not count, as the backslash makes it a regular argument for 'find' and therefore no longer a command terminator.

The correct command would be:

```
archive_gs() { find "$GS" -maxdepth 1 -not -newer "$1" -exec mv -t "$GS/../old/" {} \;; }
```